# Out-File: cannot find part of path

Tags: cmd.exe, qt

I tried to follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lwX_urJJOf8) that explains how to download a static mingw builder for Qt, but I got this error. I did follow the steps that were mentioned. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

```
Out-File: cannot find part of path  C:\Qt\Static591\5.12.3_Static\mkspecs\win32-g++\qmake.conf

At C:\Qt\windows-build-qt-static.ps1:178 char:6
+ "@ | Out-File -Append $File -Encoding Ascii
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo: OpenError: (:) [Out-File], DirectoryNotFoundException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorID: FileOpenFailure, Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand
```

my batchfile looks like this:

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& 'C:\Qt\windows-build-qt-static' 
    -QtSrcUrl 'https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.12/5.12.3/single/qt-everywhere-src-5.12.3.zip' -QtStaticDir 'C:\Qt\Static591' 
    -MingwDir 'C:\Qt\Tools\mingw730_32' -QtVersion '5.12.3_Static'
```

Comment: Did you verify that the path exists? The PowerShell error suggest that something below `C:\Qt` doesn't exist.

Comment: C:\Qt does in fact exist. The folder \mkspecs\win32-g++\ should've been made by that script, but it didn't. I'm assuming that some part of the installation went wrong.

Comment: I never said it didn't but the part below it `Static591\5.12.3_Static` might not be. Especially since you left that out. Anyway, the error does tell you what the issue is. The qmake.conf at that particular locations wasn't accessible/doesn't exist as part of the path doesn't. Create it and/or adapt your build process. I don't get why you'd use a batch file if you need to run a PowerShell script anyway.

Comment: I have absolutely zero knowledge about this, but I need to deploy a Qt application to 1 .exe file.
The path: C:\Qt\Static591\5.12.3_Static 
exists, but it's empty, so the underlying \mkspecs\win32-g++\ do not exists, but it should've been created using that script (according to the video)

Comment: So you will need to verify each step and checkout where something didn't work. The source of the script seems to be [qt.io which has an article about it](https://wiki.qt.io/Building_a_static_Qt_for_Windows_using_MinGW). Make sure to check the prerequisites.